# Attempting to rotate a list via slicing without creating a new array

Tags: python-2.7

So I’m still learning python but the idea is i need to take a list for example my_list[1,2,3,4] and rotate the last 2 index's. So the new list will print like this my_list = [3,4,1,2].

The problem is I can't create a new list to store the values into even as a temp so i have to do everything in line. I've read a lot of stuff on slicing but I guess I’m just missing the memo on this one. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like ```my_list[-2:]+my_list[:-2]```? If not then could you please explain with a bigger list?

Comment: @TrigonaMinima the idea is to rotate the list to the left using slicing. So if list a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,0] if you rotated it 2 left you would get list a = [9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]. The problem im having is doing it inline without creating a new list and it has to be done with slicing. From what i've read this isnt a normal use for slicing, or at least one I havn't found documentation on yet.

Comment: Then the solution I have provided should work. Just assign it back to ```my_list```. Or you can't even do that?

Comment: @TrigonaMinima No that does exactly what i needed thank you for the help!